# Text to speech translation via google translate

Tags: text-to-speech, google-translate

Can this audio [tool](http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=Hello) from Google Translate be used in commercial applications. It does have lots of limitations like the following:-

1. Doesn't translate if the words contain a "." or "'"
2. Doesn't translate if the sentence contains more words.
3. Is this tool supported from Google, where do you post support questions related to this

Is there an equivalent open source tool apart from Google Translate which can be used in commercial applications

Answer (score 1):

[CMUsphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/) and [voxforge](http://www.voxforge.org/) are two I've heard of that are Opensource, but i think they're only Speech recognition softwares, you'd have to work with a text to speech tool as well.

Comment: am just interested in text-2-speech tools much similar to google translate and easy to use (since its available on the internet)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for stealing your question (although I think I solved your question)

I use googles translation text-to-speech tool in this application http://gustavstromberg.se/sandbox/html5/localstorage/

Simply type or speak something to the input field and then store it. Then you can listen to the memo, but the playback only works in safari.

I explained a bit more here: [HTML5 speech input and Google Translate text-to-speech, problem in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050866/html5-speech-input-and-google-translate-text-to-speech-problem-in-chrome)

I am very eager to get this to work, would have been such a cool voice memo application.