# Use word-speaker on a site (as google translate)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, audio

I've found [annyang](https://www.talater.com/annyang/) for speech recognition and now I want to use anybody "word-speaker" with accent in my chat(ASP.NET MVC 5 + SignalR + Angular) as google translate. But I cant find suitable service ... Google translate is not working correctly. For example:

```
var audio = new Audio('http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=ru&q="привет"');
audio.play();
```

Sometimes it sends Status "Canceled". Does anybody know why? Can you help me find suitable service?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 speech input and Google Translate text-to-speech, problem in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050866/html5-speech-input-and-google-translate-text-to-speech-problem-in-chrome)